# How to get a soft keyboard to display in a HTML5/CSS3 website?

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, keyboard

I'm working on a mobile web application and I have a problem with the Android soft keyboard when an input field is focused.

When I focus the input field, the soft keyboard appears. On Windows Phone (tested on 7.8) the whole page, so the entire DOM goes up to make room for the softkeyboard. With Android (and also on Google Chrome) some elements stay where they are, and others go up when the soft keyboard is openend. How can I get the whole DOM, or actually, the hole body of the page to go up to make room for the soft keyboard on Android (I haven't tested this on iOS yet).

Here are a few screenshots on Android when the keyboard is opened:

**Here is what the page looks like when it's normal:**

[image: a busy cat]

**And this is what it looks like when the soft keyboard is opened:**

[image: a busy cat]

***How can I get this effect?:***

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: Maybe the css will be helpful to see. If you are using a fixed position then thats the problem.

Comment: I use absolute positions, not fixed. But without absolute, the page goes all crazy with elements floating everywhere. The main wrapper that holds everything, has positions: absolute.

Comment: Try changing it and test if something changes. I can´t garatee how the browser will interpret the positions but I´m pretty sure thats the problem.

Comment: Well, I've tested this on iOS and it works just fine. So only Android causes trouble (didn't expect that... tested on a HTC One). The wrapper has position absolute, as well as the header, the logo etc, but they have to have position absolute to just stay at the right place. I really don't know what to do about this.

Comment: Each browser implements things differently so Android isn´t adjusting the absolute position after the keyboard is shown. Try using this on document.ready() ---> $('#appMain').resize();

Comment: Could you explain just a little bit what this does and how it's likely to fix the problem?

Comment: It pushes the browser to fire the resize method over the main div, maybe that might help for the div to adjust correctly. I really can´t tell because I´m not testing it neither in the emulator nor a phone bue you can try.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
<meta name="MobileOptimized" content="width" />
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
<!-- CSS -->
<style>
    @charset "UTF-8";

    body{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    input, textarea, button {
        outline: none;
    }

    #appMain {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 640px;
        height: 100%;
        background: url(static/img/static/main_bg.fw.png) no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    }

    #appHeader {
        position: absolute;
        margin: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        background: #007EA8;
    }

    #headerUnderline {
        position: absolute;
        margin-top: 50px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 5px;
        background: #CCC;
    }

    #headerLogo {
        position: absolute;
        left: -50px;
        width: 125px;
        height: 72px;
        background: url(static/img/static/sprite.fw.png);
        background-position: 0 0;
    }

    #mainLogo {
        width: 80%;
        margin-left: 10%;
        margin-right: 10%;
        margin-top: 100px;
    }

    #mainSlogan {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        font: 20px sans-serif;
        color: #FFF;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
    }

    #footer {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        background: red;
    }

    #facebook {
        margin: 0;
        padding-left: 30px;
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
        height: 100%;
        font: 14px sans-serif;
        color: #FFF;
        background: #003A75;
        border: 0;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
    }

    #signIn {
        margin: 0;
        float: right;
        width: 50%;
        height: 100%;
        font: 14px sans-serif;
        color: #FFF;
        background: #007900;
        border: 0;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
    }

    #facebookLogo {
        position: absolute;
        left: 4%;
        top: 10px;
        width: 16px;
        height: 30px;
        background: url(static/img/static/sprite.fw.png);
        background-position: -160px -30px;
    }

    #fieldHolder {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        bottom: 100px;
    }

    .accountField {
        margin-bottom: -2px;
        padding-left: 5px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
        border: 0;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font: 14px sans-serif;
        color: #333;
    }

    .accountField:focus {
        background: #FFF;
    }

    .accountField::-webkit-input-placeholder {
       color: #FFF;
    }

    .accountField2::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
       color: #FFF;  
    }

    .accountField:-ms-input-placeholder {  
       color: #FFF;  
    }

    #subFooter {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 65px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    #signUpButton {
        margin-left: 10px;
        float: left;
        background: none;
        border: 0;
        font: 14px sans-serif;
        color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #forgotButton {
        margin-right: 10px;
        float: right;
        background: none;
        border: 0;
        font: 14px sans-serif;
        color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
</style>
    <!-- JS -->
<script src="static/js/includes/jquery_m.js"></script>
<script src="static/js/includes/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="appMain">
    <div id="appHeader">
        <div id="headerUnderline"></div>
        <div id="headerLogo"></div>
    </div>
    <img id="mainLogo" src="static/img/static/main_logo.fw.png" alt="Welcome to     Scrapll!" />
    <h1 id="mainSlogan">The Private Social Network<h1>
    <form action="login.php" method="post">
        <div id="fieldHolder">
            <input type="email" class="accountField" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" />
            <input type="password" class="accountField" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
        </div>
        <div id="subFooter">
            <a href="index.php" type="button" id="signUpButton" data-transition="slide">Sign Up</a>
            <a href="index.php" type="button" id="forgotButton" data-transition="slide">Forgot password</a>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <input type="submit" id="signIn" value="Sign In" />
    </form>
            <button type="button" id="facebook">Login with Facebook</button>
            <div id="facebookLogo"></div>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```